# Distinguishing the differences in meanings when of, by, in, through, with & for are added before the Spirit?

Tags: greek, word-study, grammar, authorial-intent

All taken from KJV for consistencey

> [Romans 15:30](https://biblehub.com/romans/15-30.htm) Now I beseech you, brethren, for the Lord Jesus
>   Christ's sake, and for the love **of the Spirit**, that ye strive together
>   with me in your prayers to God for me;
>
> [1 John 3:24](https://biblehub.com/1_john/3-24.htm) And he that keepeth his commandments dwelleth in him,
>   and he in him. And hereby we know that he abideth in us, **by the Spirit**
>   which he hath given us.
>
> [Galatians 5:5](https://biblehub.com/galatians/5-5.htm) For we through the Spirit wait for the hope of
>   righteousness by faith.
>   [Galatians 5:16](https://biblehub.com/galatians/5-16.htm) This I say then, Walk **in the Spirit**, and ye shall
>   not fulfil the lust of the flesh.
>
> [Romans 8:13](https://biblehub.com/romans/8-13.htm) For if ye live after the flesh, ye shall die: but if
>   ye **through the Spirit** do mortify the deeds of the body, ye shall live.
>
> [1 Corinthians 14:15](https://biblehub.com/1_corinthians/14-15.htm) What is it then? I will pray **with the spirit**,
>   and I will pray with the understanding also: I will sing with the
>   spirit, and I will sing with the understanding also.

What difference in meaning is implied when **of**, **by**, **in**, **through** & **with** are added before **the Spirit**?. I am a not a native english speaker. How ever I am looking beyond the english grammar to the original language to learn the differences.

Comment: This is a broad question, indeed.

Comment: So knowledge of some URLs/Resources in the Internet or books I can buy to study them in detail would be just fine. I am not looking for a complete answer here. If some one can provide me the basic meanings I could get started. Or if you want me to split the question further please advise.

Comment: It would be best to make a separate question for each one and ask the meaning of the phrase in question. Is that okay with you? If so, we can make this question specifically about Romans 15:30.

Comment: I wanted to distinguish the differences, is the edit fine?

Comment: Let us see what others think about the broadness of the question. I've rolled it back to the original question at this time. If need be, we can always revert it back to your edit.

Comment: Prepositions receive a meaning from their usage within the larger phrase. Thus we should look at "love of", "know by", "walk in", "mortify through", "pray with" (in 1 Peter 4:14, "for" is not a preposition; it cannot be compared). But then it would be more interesting to compare cases where the head is the same (e.g., "pray by" vs. "pray in" vs. "pray through" vs. "pray with", if these exist). Such a question would in my opinion not be too broad (if it would be split up, you cannot compare the various references); however, the question as it stands seems rather meaningless to me.

Comment: The heading seemed to be mutilated somehow. So I added the rest again.

Comment: @Keelan I deleted the part with "for". Is the question meaningful now?

Comment: @SijuGeorge—It seems the general consensus is that it is too broad of a question. It would be best to ask separate question for each verse. We can edit this question to focus on one verse. About which verse would you like to ask here?

Comment: Yes it’s too broad and I didn’t answer this version of the question. Now my answer makes no sense because the context has changed. Also I wouldn’t know how to answer this version of the question. It was hard enough when it was shorter.

Comment: @DerÜbermensch Could it be edited to ask the difference between "in the", "through the", "by the" & "with the" ?. Jesse Steele has given the answer I am looking for already.

Comment: The other issue I mentioned has not been addressed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question relates to **[Noun Case](http://www.bcbsr.com/greek/gcase.html)** in the original language, Greek.

*Generally, if you want to be precise with prepositions and words from the original language, you should use the NASB because it was intended for that purpose.*

The prepositions in English Bible translations are intended to reflect the prepositions as they are used with the case of their nouns in Greek. But, the Greek offers much more clarity than English. So, you must go to the Greek for a fuller understanding. The more familiar you are with Greek, the better (or 'less inaccurately') you will be able to guess what is going on by looking at English.

So, let's dive in with your Holy Spirit prepositions, in your order... *(NASB, SBLGNT)*

*These include NASB, followed by Greek for the "___ spirit" in bold below, followed by general knowledge of the noun case, and lastly my opinion of "use" and interpretation thereof...*

**Romans 15:30**

> Now I urge you, brethren, by our Lord Jesus Christ and by the love **of the Spirit**, to strive together with me in your prayers to God for me,
>
> **τοῦ πνεύματος**

Case: **Genitive** Use: Possessive/relation/source

Could be translated "[by] the Spirit's [love]"

*Meaning:* Not only our own love or love from/for other people, but a love that comes from the Holy Spirit. Things needing to come from the Holy Spirit is a common topic and theme in the New Testament.

**1 John 3:24**

> The one who keeps His commandments abides in Him, and He in him. We know by this that He abides in us, **by the Spirit** whom He has given us.
>
> **ἐκ τοῦ πνεύματος**

Case: **Genitive** Use: Source

Could be translated "[This is how we know He abides in us: ] due to the Spirit"

*Meaning:* The evident fact that He gave us the Spirit–from miracles, an empowered life, and supernatural love–proves that God does in fact lives inside of us.

**Galatians 5:5**

> For we **through the Spirit**, by faith, are waiting for the hope of righteousness.
>
> **πνεύματι**

Case: **Dative** Use: Means/manner/sphere

Could be translated "in Spirit" or "with (the Holy) Spirit"

*Meaning:* While we wait for this reliable hope, the good and fair things that will surely come, we are not alone or abandoned, but we are waiting in the strong and encouraging presence of the Holy Spirit.

**Galatians 5:16-17a** (The follow-up into the next sentence is needed for completion.)

> *16* But I say, walk **by the Spirit**, and you will not carry out the desire of the flesh. *17* For the flesh sets its desire **against the Spirit**...
>
> **πνεύματι**
>
> **κατὰ τοῦ πνεύματος**

*First*

Case: **Dative** Use: Means/manner

Could be translated "[walk] with the Spirit" or "[walk] Spiritually" (capital 'S')

*Second*

Case: **Genitive** Use: Separation/Direct Object

Could be translated "contrary to the Spirit"

*Meaning:* The word comes very early in the sentence and has neither article nor preposition, meaning it is emphasized. We could even be inventive and translate it, "[I say:] 'Spirit-walk' and you won't do what flesh desires." The word "walk" is just as important, meaning "how we live", or the "walk" of "walk your talk". If we walk-out our lives immersed in God's Holy Spirit, the lower temptations and hungers of our flesh won't control us.

*Expanded meaning:* In the second occurrence, Paul mentions "flesh... against the Spirit". This means that the flesh has set itself against the Spirit, so they are contrary because the flesh decided so, but the Spirit remains the stronger of the two. The Spirit didn't pick the fight with the flesh, but the Spirit ended it, so side with the Spirit and you'll win.

**Romans 8:13**

> for if you are living according to the flesh, you must die; but if **by the Spirit** you are putting to death the deeds of the body, you will live.
>
> **πνεύματι**

*A lot could be said about this because of "according to the flesh" that it is juxtaposed against, but I'll not give into that temptation today. Suffice it to say, "Spirit" can stand by itself because the noun case of "Spirit" is different from "flesh".*

Case: **Dative** Use: Manner/means

Could be translated: "[but if/when] by Spirit"

*Meaning:* This has much of the same use, form, spelling, and meaning as Galatians 5.

**1 Corinthians 14:15**

> What is the outcome then? I will pray **with the spirit** and I will pray with the mind also; I will sing **with the spirit** and I will sing with the mind also.
>
> **τῷ πνεύματι** (same both times)

Case: **Dative** Use: Means

Could be translated "in spirit" or "with spirit" *(Paul is not necessarily talking about the Holy Spirit, but possibly his own spirit–such as praying in tongues, maybe. Either way, the Holy Spirit is certainly implicated.)*

*Meaning:* Paul is comparing the difference between praying based on ideas of his cognitive, calculation-focused mind vs praying with his own spirit or possibly praying "spiritually" with God's Holy Spirit. Based on his other uses the word for "spirit" (above), Paul is basically saying, "If you *pray by the Spirit* when you pray, just as you should *walk by the Spirit* as you walk-out your life, then your prayer also will be more empowering than if you merely, so-called 'pray' by calculated cognition in the lifeless math of your mind." Prayer is a spiritual, spirit-sensing, sixth-sense activity–possibly including a prayer language (a different topic not directly addressed in this verse), but not only limited to that. Real, genuine prayer for the Christian, unlike the mind-driven obsession with Greek philosophy of that day, should be a near-but-not-quite "out-of-body" experience. Paul is *not* saying that the mind is bad, but that the Spirit and the mind must *both* be involved in healthy, useful Christian prayer.

Answer (score -1):

In the first instance it’s the Holy Spirit, and we act through the Spirit in the sense that we surrender our bodies and members to Him so that He can use us as He pleases for His glory. In the first verse the Spirit is acting on our surrendered soul and in the second our surrendered fleshly bodies. That’s the theory, the practical aspect takes time because we have the flesh conspiring with the soul against our spirit.

That’s where the second part 1 Cor 14:15 comes in. Without going into when or if the spirit was dead prior to the rebirth or being born of the Spirit, after the Holy Spirit comes into the life of the believer the believer’s spirit can commune with the Holy Spirit. It can have connection, which it didn’t have prior, certainly it could not understand the things of the Spirit, nor accept them. If anything most likely the unregenerate person was influenced at the soul level (will, emotion, intellect).

When the believer communes in the spirit with the Spirit, the spirit in order to act upon the flesh/body must filter through the soul (will, emotion, intellect). Because the soul is unregenerated amd we need to renew our minds the information can be distorted.

When Apostle Paul says I will pray with the spirit, he means speaking in tongues which is the only example where the spirit can bypass the soul and no distortion occurs. The Spirit gives the spirit a message in a language the soul can not understand and the body speaks it out loud.

When Apsotle Paul prays with his mind, he is engaging this soul/intellect as well. Both prayers are good, but praying in the spirit in tongues, helps prevent any interference for fallen corrupted thinking. In this way the Spirit can pray a prayer that is completely according to His will.

So in conclusion even though I haven’t provided Bible verses, through the Spirit means you have surrendered your body and soul and whatever you do is done through the Spirit’s guidance, you obey at the soul level, will, emotion, intellect. In the spirit means your spirit engages the Spirit and acts upon the body and/or the soul.

Comment: You edited you question?

Comment: I rolled it back so we can gather a general consensus on whether the original was indeed too broad. I would keep your answer as-is for now and let's wait and see what happens.

Comment: "he means speaking in tongues which is the only example where the spirit can bypass the soul and no distortion occurs" "Tongues" just means "languages." Nowhere does the Bible mention the gift of speaking in other languages in conjunction with not being able to understand those languages. It was rather the very miracle of the gift—that those who came from all around *could* understand in their own language. Nor is it mentioned in conjunction with a 'more infallible' or 'pure' word or message. The Apostles preached the gospel as they would if others could *not* understand them.

Comment: Actually whether it’s a tongue or language it’s irrelevant the point is it cannot be understood by the speaker unless he or someone else can interpret. “Therefore let one who speaks in a tongue pray that he may interpret. For if I pray in a tongue, my spirit prays, but my mind is unfruitful.”
‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭14:13-14‬ ‭NASB‬‬ so as you can see it is in the Bible. Please read the whole context of these verses and tell me how you still hold your view that the language will be understood without an interpreter.